# DVTPlugInManager: Required plug-in compatibility not present

Tags: xcode

Keep seeing this error log from the terminal when pushing to git repo lately. I think it is due to fact that I updated to Xcode 9.2 or macOS High Sierra.

> 2017-11-29 07:49:30.580 xcodebuild[1558:49212] [MT] DVTPlugInManager: Required plug-in compatibility UUID C3998872.. for KSImageNamed.ideplugin (com.ksuther.KSImageNamed) not present

Any idea what it means and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It sounds like you have an old Xcode plugin installed. I had this same error and I found the old plugin located in

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Plug-ins/`

The file name was `KSImageNamed.ideplugin`

I'd recommend deleting the file.